# Java 8 - Sort a List by Map's Key and Value

Tags: java, sorting, dictionary, java-8, comparator

End goal is to sort the list for the following scenario:

I have an enum with the BLOCKER being the highest severity an MINOR being the lowest.

```
public enum Severity {
    MINOR(0)
    MAJOR(1),
    BLOCKER(2);
```

I have a class SeverityProfile

```
public class SeverityProfile {

    private final Map<Severity, Integer> severities;

    public SeverityProfile(Map<Severity, Integer> severities) {
        this.severities = Collections.unmodifiableMap(severities);
    }

    public Map<Severity, Integer> getSeverities() {
        return severities;
    }
```

The main object AggregatedData

```
public class AggregatedData {

 
    private final SeverityProfile severityProfile;
    ... other private variables

    public AggregatedData(SeverityProfile severityProfile) {

        this.severityProfile = severityProfile;
  
    }


    public SeverityProfile getSeverityProfile() {
        return severityProfile;
    }
    ... other getters
}
```

Now, I have to sort the  `List<AggregatedData> aggregatedData` by the Severity of the map.
`aggregatedData.get(0).getSeverityProfile().getSeverities()` has BLOCKER - 1 and MAJOR - 2
`aggregatedData.get(1).getSeverityProfile().getSeverities()` has BLOCKER - 3 and MAJOR - 2 and MINOR - 4
`aggregatedData.get(2).getSeverityProfile().getSeverities()` has MAJOR - 2 and MINOR - 8
`aggregatedData.get(3).getSeverityProfile().getSeverities()` has MAJOR - 5 and MINOR - 10

If I want the descending values, then the result should be:

- `aggregatedData.get(1)` - BLOCKER - 3 and MAJOR - 2 and MINOR - 4
- `aggregatedData.get(0)` - BLOCKER - 1 and MAJOR - 2
- `aggregatedData.get(3)` - MAJOR - 5 and MINOR - 10
- `aggregatedData.get(2)` - MAJOR - 2 and MINOR - 8

(Notice MAJOR which is next priority to BLOCKER has higher count in get(3) than get(2))

I'd like to do a  `Collections.sort(aggregatedData, new Comparator<AggregatedData>() {`

Problem is, I have to compare the `Severity` and also the values associated with it.
I'm not sure how to construct the Comparator in this case.

Comment: does the `SeverityProfile` have getters to access only the numbers for a given severity, something like `....getSeverityProfile().getSeverityData(BLOCKER)`?

Comment: So you're populating `severities` inside `SeverityProfile` with the data and for example have them sorted within the `SeverityProfile` constructor?

Comment: you can order your Severity and use ordinal to compare them

Comment: The first step is to describe precisely, in a human language, the rules that result in your example. Write those rules as comments. Tackle writing code for them one-by-one. One of those rules will involve comparing one severity for two SeverityProfiles ...

Comment: @Hulk Since, it's map, we can do - ```getSeverityProfile().getSeverities().getOrDefault(Severity.BLOCKER, 0)```

Comment: @Dropout Yes, the ```severities``` is being populated in the ```SeverityProfile``` and I'd like to sort the list that has the ```SeverityProfile``` object based on the map's key and value.

Comment: @CLAINCyril If you don't mind, can you point me to an example on the usage of ordinal? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

```
public class SeverityProfile implements Comparable<SeverityProfile> {

    private final Map<Severity, Integer> severities;

    private final int[] counts;

    public SeverityProfile(Map<Severity, Integer> severities) {
        counts = new int[Severity.values().length];

        this.severities = Collections.unmodifiableMap(severities);

        counts[Severity.BLOCKER.ordinal()] = severities.getOrDefault(Severity.BLOCKER, 0);
        counts[Severity.MAJOR.ordinal()] = severities.getOrDefault(Severity.MAJOR, 0);
        counts[Severity.MINOR.ordinal()] = severities.getOrDefault(Severity.MINOR, 0);
    }


    public Map<Severity, Integer> getSeverities() {
        return severities;
    }

    public int[] getCounts() {
        return counts;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(SeverityProfile other) {
        if (other == this) {
            return 0;
        }

        for (Severity severity : Severity.getSeveritiesByDescendingRank()) {
            if (getCounts()[severity.ordinal()] != other.getCounts()[severity.ordinal()]) {
                return getCounts()[severity.ordinal()] - other.getCounts()[severity.ordinal()];

            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I used Comparator in the `Collections.sort` and used the above `compareTo` method.